interpolate sequence for different objects
so i have a picture with around 30 leaves, drawn in grease pencil. now i want them to fly from A to B in 200 frames. I did it with one leave in edit mode, to try if it works. I interpolated the sequence and it works fine.
Now the problem. I want to do the same for alle the other 29 leaves, but somehow i can't interpolate them. The one leave from the beginning flys from A to B, while all the others stay at A until frame 200 and then jump to B. How can I interpolate the sequence for all the other objects?
